# Scikit Learn - Diagnosing when parallel jobs get stuck

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

What is the proper way to diagnose what is happening when parallel jobs get stuck in Scikit-Learn?

Specifically, I have had several jobs that appear to finish (htop shows no CPU activity), but python stops responding.  Pressing `Ctrl+c` doesn't exit (though it does register a KeyboardInterrupt, it doesn't kill the python process), and the process must be killed from shell.  Total memory usage approaches the capacity of the machine, but I get no explicit errors that there was a MemoryError.

This has occurred with `RandomForestRegressor`, and also with `cross_validation.cross_val_score`, under both 0.14 and `master` on Ubuntu/Debian.

I suspect this is a memory issue, since the jobs seem to complete without a problem on machines with more memory.

Comment: scikit-learn 0.14.1 and earlier do not always detect out of memory conditions in random forests; that was fixed just last weekend. You could try the current `master` version to see if you get better error messages.

Comment: @larsmans can you point me to the ticket that documents the fix and the expected behavior?  I have a version of master from a couple of days ago, but maybe I'll pull and try again.

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2715

Comment: @larsmans was the problem only with random forests?  This happened to me once with GridSearchCV and RandomForest, but parallelized at the grid search level (RandomForest ran with n_jobs=1)

Comment: It was a problem specific to decision trees and all models based on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to definitively find the cause of this problem, but it stopped happening when I increased the amount of memory available.  So it seems reasonable to conclude that one of the children processes encountered a `MemoryError` and just died.